# Monogame: Render only inside specified area

Tags: c#, monogame

This may be a strange question, but I'm trying to find a way to render sprites only inside a specific allowed area rather then the entire buffer/texture.

Like so:
[image]

Basically allowing me to draw to the buffer or texture2D as I normally would, but with actual drawing happening only inside this specified area and remaining pixels outside of it remaining untouched.

Why this is needed - I'm building my own UI system and I would like to avoid using intermediary buffers as it is quite slow when there are many UI components on the screen (and each has to draw to their own buffer to prevent child elements being drawn outside of parent bounds).

And just to clarify - this is all for simple 2D rendering, not 3D.

Comment: I don't really get the UI issue. I've also written my own UI system and nerver ran into performance issues. SpriteBatch.Draw is very good performing. 
But still. What you need is a ViewPort representing the currently visible part of the screen. You can simpy check if the coordinates of the object that has to be drawn is outside this viewPort or not.

Comment: Look up `RenderTarget2D`.

Answer (score 1):

If your UI is actually drawn with SpriteBatch you can use ScissorRectangle

```
GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState.ScissorTestEnable = true;
spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.ScissorRectangle = ...
```

In 3D, you can render to a texture and draw just a portion of it - or with a shader (you could actually just send in the dimensions as parameter and set it to black in PixelShader if the Pixel is outside that Rectangle (or whatever you want to accomplish)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(yourTexture,
    //where and the size of what you want to draw on screen
    //for example, new Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 50)//position and width, height
    destinationRectangle,
    //the area you want to draw from the original texture
    //for example, new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50)//position and width, height
    sourceRectangle,
    Color.White);
```

Then it will only draw the area that you chose before. Hope this helps!